# How to make django not to ask for migrations?

Tags: django

When I run my Django project. It prints the following:

```
You have 17 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
```

I'm using raw queries and not using admin and models feature. So migrations will not be of any use for me.
How can I make Django to not ask for applying migration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The settings file generated by `django-admin startproject` has several apps listed in `INSTALLED_APPS`. Go through that list and remove all apps you are not using.

Answer (score 0):

Django migration maintains database and model schema same. It is preferable to use django migration to make both schema same, but there are some cases where you don't want to migrate database using your Django application like If you are using third party database, multiple application is using same database or your application purpose is read only. For such cases you can use fake migration to ignore propagating changes in database.

`python manage.py migrate --fake`